# fileInput not returning any dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to input two files, to perform some transformations and to return a data table. It works fine if I hardcode the file path but not if I use `fileInput`. I'm using `obersveEvent` because the options and operations are a bit more complex of what I show in the reproducible example.
Any suggestions on what might be wrong with the code?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
library(DT)

##
ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Test app"),
  sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("Env_db1", "Choose CSV File for DB1",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv") 
      ),

      fileInput("Env_db2", "Choose CSV File for DB2",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv") 
      )
    ,
    actionButton(
      inputId = "submit_loc",
      label = "Submit")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table"))

  )
)


##
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$submit_loc,
    handlerExpr = 
    {
        req(input$file1)
        inFile1 <- input$file1
        if(is.null(input$file1))     return(NULL) 
        Env_1<- read.csv(inFile1$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ";")


        req(input$file2)
        inFile2 <- input$file2
        if(is.null(input$file2))     return(NULL) 
        Env_2 <- read.csv(inFile2$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ";")


      Difference <-rbind(Env_1,Env_2)

      output$table = DT::renderDataTable(server = TRUE,{
        DT::datatable(Difference,
                      extensions=c("Buttons",'Scroller'),
                      options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                     buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 
                                                 'excel', 'pdf', 
                                                 'print'),
                                     scrollY = 500,
                                     scroller = TRUE)
        )
      })
    })
})  
##
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your `fileInput` variable are wrong instead of `input$file1` and `input$file2` it should be `input$Env_db1` and `input$Env_db2`. Replacing the variables as shown below, your code works fine.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
library(DT)

##
ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("DBC Comparison"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("Env_db1", "Choose CSV File for DB1",
              accept = c(
                "text/csv",
                "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                ".csv") 
    ),

    fileInput("Env_db2", "Choose CSV File for DB2",
              accept = c(
                "text/csv",
                "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                ".csv") 
    )
    ,
    actionButton(
      inputId = "submit_loc",
      label = "Submit")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table"))

)
)


##
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$submit_loc,
    handlerExpr = 
    {
      req(input$Env_db1)
      inFile1 <- input$Env_db1
      if(is.null(input$Env_db1))     return(NULL) 
      Env_1<- read.csv(inFile1$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ";")


      req(input$Env_db2)
      inFile2 <- input$Env_db2
      if(is.null(input$Env_db2))     return(NULL) 
      Env_2 <- read.csv(inFile2$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ";")


      Difference <-rbind(Env_1,Env_2)

      output$table = DT::renderDataTable(server = TRUE,{
        DT::datatable(Difference,
                      extensions=c("Buttons",'Scroller'),
                      options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                     buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 
                                                 'excel', 'pdf', 
                                                 'print'),
                                     scrollY = 500,
                                     scroller = TRUE)
        )
      })
    })
})  
##
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Mistakenly you have used `file1` in your server.R to refer the input file object which you are reading as `Env_db1`

Updated code:

```
  library(shiny)
  library(shinydashboard)
  library(data.table)
  library(DT)

  ##
  ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("DBC Comparison"),
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("Env_db1", "Choose CSV File for DB1",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv") 
      ),

      fileInput("Env_db2", "Choose CSV File for DB2",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv") 
      )
      ,
      actionButton(
        inputId = "submit_loc",
        label = "Submit")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table"))

  )
  )


  ##
  server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(
      eventExpr = input$submit_loc,
      handlerExpr = 
      {
        req(input$Env_db1)
        inFile1 <- input$Env_db1
        if(is.null(input$Env_db1))     return(NULL) 
        Env_1<- read.csv(inFile1$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ";")


        req(input$Env_db2)
        inFile2 <- input$Env_db2
        if(is.null(input$Env_db2))     return(NULL) 
        Env_2 <- read.csv(inFile2$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ";")


        Difference <-rbind(Env_1,Env_2)

        output$table = DT::renderDataTable(server = TRUE,{
          DT::datatable(Difference,
                        extensions=c("Buttons",'Scroller'),
                        options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                       buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 
                                                   'excel', 'pdf', 
                                                   'print'),
                                       scrollY = 500,
                                       scroller = TRUE)
          )
        })
      })
  })  
  ##
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```